# Android: TRying to have 2 web views on top of each other, only top one gets drawn

Tags: android

I'm trying to have a layout with 2 web view.  I cannot figure out why the bottom one does not get displayed. The one on top has a TextView that gets displayed.  Then there is a big space under it, where the webview is suppose to be. I'v done this before.

the layout has 2 vertical containers, inside  a horizontal container.  The first vertical container has the two webvies

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bookmarkbackground"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


 <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"   
  android:orientation="horizontal">    

<!-- right hand side, has web vues for next event and current message threads -->
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"   
  android:orientation="vertical">  

     <TextView      
        android:id="@+id/textPush"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Latest Message Board Threads"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/> >



// this one gets displayed
               <WebView
           android:id="@+id/webAuthor"
           android:layout_width="200px"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1.0"
           />   

               <TextView        
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Latest Message Board Threads"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />  

               // is not getting displayed
               <WebView
           android:id="@+id/webThreads"
           android:layout_width="200px"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1.0"
           /> 

          </LinearLayout>  




<!-- left hand side should over lay book mark and have buttons -->
    <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"   
  android:orientation="vertical">  

          <TextView     
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Latest Message Board Threads"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"     
                 />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"   
  android:orientation="vertical">  

     <TextView      
        android:id="@+id/textPush"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Latest Message Board Threads"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/> 


           <WebView
       android:id="@+id/webAuthor"
       android:layout_width="200px"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1.0"
       />   

           <TextView        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Latest Message Board Threads"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />  

           // is not getting displayed
           <WebView
       android:id="@+id/webThreads"
       android:layout_width="200px"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1.0"
       /> 

      </LinearLayout>
```

Usually if you specify  `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` the **weight** are not applied appropriately.